# I cant insert data into my DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, winforms

I'm trying  to insert data into my DB and when i press the button it should get done but it won't

I guess it's from my last layer somewhere in my Query

here's my code

```
   public void InsertInventory(DateTime _date, int _customer_Id,
                            int _employee_Id, List<int> _product_Id,
                            List<int> _amountSold,
                            List<int> _unitPrice, List<int> _totalPrice)
    {
        Connection_String = @"Data Source=MOSTAFA-PC;Initial Catalog="
                           + "Sales and Inventory System"
                           + ";Integrated Security=TrueData Source=MOSTAFA-PC;Initial Catalog="
                           + "Sales and Inventory System"
                           + ";Integrated Security=True;";

        Query = "insert into Inventory" +
                  "(Customer_Id,Employee_Id,Product_Id,[Date],[Amount Sold],[Unit Price],[Total Price])" +
                    "values (@customer_id,@Employee_id,@Product_id,@[Date],@[Amount_Sold],@[Unit_Price],@[Total_Price])";

        using (Con = new SqlConnection(Connection_String))
        using (Cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, Con))
        {
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@customer_id", SqlDbType.Int);
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Employee_id", SqlDbType.Int);
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Product_id", SqlDbType.Int);
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@[Date]", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            //Cmd.Parameters.Add("@[Date]", SqlDbType.Date);
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@[Amount_sold]", SqlDbType.Int);
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@[Unit_Price]", SqlDbType.Decimal);
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Total_Price", SqlDbType.Decimal);

            Cmd.Connection = Con;
            Con.Open();

            int RecordToAdd = _product_Id.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < RecordToAdd; i++)
            {
                Cmd.Parameters["@customer_id"].Value = _customer_Id;
                Cmd.Parameters["@Employee_id"].Value = _employee_Id;
                Cmd.Parameters["@Product_id"].Value = _product_Id;
                Cmd.Parameters["@Date"].Value = _date;
                Cmd.Parameters["@Amount_sold"].Value = _amountSold;
                Cmd.Parameters["@Unit_Price"].Value = _unitPrice;
                Cmd.Parameters["@Total_Price"].Value = _totalPrice;
                Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

    }
```

I can't figure it out where my problem is

Comment: your problem is you have no error handling

Comment: Add _int records = Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();_ and then use a MessageBox to show the records variable. It should be 1 if the record has been inserted or zero if not. Also, that connection string text is duplicate. Is it just a typo?

Comment: By the way, you marked this with MySql TAG but this seems to be an SQL Server database from the connectionstring and from the usage of the Sql Server specific classes like SqlConnection etc... what is the correct database then?

Comment: @Steve it's microsoft sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the values that you set for your parameters.
You should use the indexer to retrieve an element from the lists not the whole lists

```
// These doesn't change inside the loop, so set it once for all...
Cmd.Parameters["@customer_id"].Value = _customer_Id;
Cmd.Parameters["@Employee_id"].Value = _employee_Id;
Cmd.Parameters["@Date"].Value = _date;

for (int i = 0; i < RecordToAdd; i++)
{
    Cmd.Parameters["@Product_id"].Value = _product_Id[i];
    Cmd.Parameters["@Amount_sold"].Value = _amountSold[i];
    Cmd.Parameters["@Unit_Price"].Value = _unitPrice[i];
    Cmd.Parameters["@Total_Price"].Value = _totalPrice[i];
    Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```